# Joining Tables and Displaying Result as Text, in one column

Tags: sql

I need to join two columns from two tables and display them in a specific order

Table1 and ColumnNM
Table2 and ColumnDESC

The Primary Key is ColumnID

I have multiple rows of ColumnDESC for each ColumnNM. So i have to display in the following format:

```
ColumnID ColumnNM
-------------------
ColumnDESC
ColumnDESC
ColumnDESC
ColumnDESC

ColumnID ColumnNM
-------------------
ColumnDESC
ColumnDESC

ColumnID ColumnNM
-------------------
ColumnDESC
ColumnDESC
ColumnDESC
```

I have to display results to text, instead of grid. Any suggestions on how to do this?
I have to create it as a stored procedure. Any help is appreciated. Below is as far as i got:

```
DECLARE @Name nvarchar(max),
@Lesson nvarchar(max),
@lb nvarchar(max)
SET @lb = '----------------------------------------------------'

SELECT  @Name = Module.Name
FROM Module
JOIN Lesson ON Module.ModuleSequence = Lesson.ModuleSequence
WHERE Module.ModuleSequence = 1
PRINT '1 ' +  @Name
PRINT @lb

SELECT Lesson.Description 
FROM Module
JOIN Lesson ON Module.ModuleSequence = Lesson.ModuleSequence
WHERE Module.ModuleSequence = 1
```

But I think I'm way off.

..........................................OKAY, EDIT, after John Tabernik suggestion i got this......................................

> (P.S. sorry about adding a comment to your answer, just learning how to use stackoverflow)

```
SELECT M.Name, L.Description
FROM Module M
    JOIN Lesson L
        ON M.ModuleSequence = L.ModuleSequence
ORDER BY M.Name, L.Description
```

I end up getting the M.Name repeated four times as there are four different L.Description for the first M.Name, and different amounts for all the other M.Name's.

Example:

```
M.Name | L.Description
-----------------------------
A      |    1
A      |    2
A      |    3
B      |    1
B      |    2
C      |    1
C      |    2
C      |    3
```

But i need it to output like this:

```
A   |
-----
1   |
2   |
3   |

B   |
-----
1   |
2   |

C   |
-----
1   |
2   |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for getting back a bit late, but I have solved what I needed. I think I worded the question a bit off. Nonetheless, below is the code i needed. Hope it inspires anyone who has similiar problem:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ShowModuleWithLessons 
@CourseID int = 0
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @MS INT
DECLARE @ModuleCount INT


SET @MS = 0
SET @ModuleCount = (Select COUNT(Module.ModuleSequence) FROM Module WHERE Module.CourseID = @CourseID)

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Module WHERE Module.CourseID = @CourseID)
BEGIN
    WHILE @MS < @ModuleCount
    BEGIN
        SET @MS=@MS+1
            DECLARE @Name nvarchar(max),
                    @Lesson nvarchar(max),
                    @CID INT
            SELECT  @Name = Module.Name,
                    @CID = @MS
            FROM Module
            JOIN Lesson ON Module.ModuleSequence = Lesson.ModuleSequence
            WHERE Module.ModuleSequence = @MS


            PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@MS) + '. ' +  @Name

            SELECT Lesson.Description AS Lessons
            FROM Module
            JOIN Lesson ON Module.ModuleSequence = Lesson.ModuleSequence
            WHERE Module.ModuleSequence = @MS
    END
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Course with ID ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@CourseID) + ' does not exists'
END
```

Answer (score 1):

How important is the sections being set apart with the header and "-------" line like you have it?  Simple SQL would not do this, but if the results can be all together and simply ordered, it is really easy.

You just want something like this:

```
SELECT column1, column2
FROM table1 T1
    JOIN table2 T2
          on T1.id = T2.foreignkey
ORDER BY column1, column2
```

You can make use of whatever pulls this data out to format it, but this general approach will get you the data, sorted the way you want.  Good luck!

Comment: +1 databases store and get the data. Formatting it nicely should be done in application layer.